# MailChimp API v3.0 Json Parse Error

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

When I try update store (Patch) I get an error in the response:

```
{
    "type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
    "title":"JSON Parse Error",
    "status":400,
    "detail":"We encountered an unspecified JSON parsing error.","instance":""
}
```

My Json data is:

```
{
    "Id":"1",
    "ListId":"lalalala",
    "Name":"Cat1",
    "Domain":"",
    "Platform":"",
    "EmailAddress":"a@a.a",
    "CurrencyCode":"USD",
    "MoneyFormat":"",
    "PrimaryLocale":"",
    "Timezone":"",
    "Phone":"",
    "Address": {
        "Address1":"",
        "Address2":"",
        "City":"",
        "Province":"",
        "ProvinceCode":"",
        "PostalCode":"",
        "Country":"",
        "CountryCode":"",
        "Longitude":0,
        "Latitude":0
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Have you tried putting your lat and long values into a string and to see if this fixes the parsing?

Comment: @Nige, it needs double values. When I perferom Post this json then it works. But not update